Workflow for Statistical Analysis of Stained Cells
I am looking for advice on how to perform analysis of my counted cell stains. I have four cell lines (one wild type, three knockouts) and three stains (GFP, DAPI, and TXRed). I am testing to see if there is a significant difference in cell counts between the wild type samples and knockouts for each of my stains. For example:
GFP: Wild type vs knockout 1, wild type vs knockout 2, wild type vs knockout 3
I've considered two approaches. The first would be to perform two-way ANOVA followed by Tukey HSD. However, the Tukey results also perform comparisons between knockouts (e.g. GFP: knockout 1 vs knockout 2) which I am not interested in.
My second ideas was to perform the individual student's t-tests then perform multiple hypothesis correction.
I am not familiar with stats, so any advice or relevant resources would be appreciated.

Look under Dunnett's post-hoc test; e.g. here on wiki, or original paper here. It does exactly what you want; it only runs comparisons to a single "control" sample; in your case wild type. Your software may or not support it for 2-way ANOVA (if it does, you will need to pick one wild stain as your control). Otherwise you can run 3 one-way ANOVA's, with adjusted $\alpha$ (e.g. Sidak $\alpha'=.017$ for 3 ANOVA's); still much better than running many t-tests (12 tests comparing all strains and all stains to the matching wild).

Thank you, Dunnett's Test is exactly what I am looking for!
